# Programming language besides Tcl where everything is string

Tags: tcl, language-features

Are there any programming languages where everything is a string. For example, let's consider this Tcl snippet (comments shows the equivalent statement in C/Java) for e.g.

```
set x [append ab cd] ;# c = "ab" + "cd"
set m 1 ;# m = 1
set n [expr $m + 1] ;# n = m + 1
```

Effectively, this is reverse of what is found in languages like C or Java; here by default what we type is a literal string unless it is a "special" word  or preceded by $ sign (in which case, the string succeeding $ is a variable).

Comment: How about PHP internals

Answer (score 1):

[Rexx (Restructured Extended Executor)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-rexx/) and [OORexx](http://www.oorexx.org/) are two languages with the same philosophy:

> In Rexx -- somewhat like in TCL -- to a large extent everything is a string. Having stacks and streams composed of lines gives you a simple list or array of strings. But mostly, strings simply act like other datatypes as needed. For example, a string that contains a suitable representation of a number (digits, decimal, an exponent "e", etc.) can be used in arithmetic operations. For processing reports, log files, and the like, this is exactly the behavior you want.

*nix has many such mini-languages. For example:

- sed
- tr
- cut
- paste
- join
- fmt
- split
- pr
- fold

**References**

- [ANSI X3J18-199X Standard for Rexx (pdf)](http://www.rexxla.org/rexxlang/standards/j18pub.pdf)
- [Rexx Functions – Standard vs Non-Standard](http://www.rexxinfo.org/Standard%20Rexx%20Functions/STANDA_1.HTM)
- [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html)
- [Tokenize a String: tr](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Tokenize_a_string#tr)
- [FizzBuzz: sed](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/FizzBuzz#Sed)
- [CSV to HTML translation: sed](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/CSV_to_HTML_translation#Sed)
- [GUI Scripting: JavaScript, Smalltalk, Tcl, AutoHotkey: Arrays - Hyperpolyglot](http://hyperpolyglot.org/gui#arrays)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your examples aren't very far removed from C or Java at all. This kind of relaxed syntax isn't uncommon in shell script languages, and it only takes a sufficiently clever preprocessor to allow it in, say, C. Lisp macros have the "everything is a literal unless I say it should be evaluated" semantics in backquoted expressions.

Tcl EIAS means it allows a program to handle different data structures, and data structures and executable code, interchangeably, with strings as common currency. This isn't unheard of: e.g. Lisp does this with lists, but it isn't all that common either. It makes Tcl extremely dynamic, and also super freaky to many programmers.

Comment: Note that "string" does not always imply "legible text".

Comment: And in fact, it doesn't even imply that the value _really_ is a string. Just that it is serializable.

Comment: @DonalFellows: well, it's going to be a string in the sense that it's a sequence of characters, right? Just not a string that the user should consume or process carelessly.

Comment: If you look at the value through a lens that only sees character sequences, that's what you'll see. What's more, _all_ values support that view; every internal value type is serializable. No guarantee about how pretty the string is, but we try to do a good job for numbers and lists and things like that.